# Querying by a list of integers in SQLiteDatabase on Android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I want to query a table in my SQLiteDatabase in Android where one of the fields is in a list of integers. Is there any way of using the query function to do this? I've tried the following code with no luck, where generatePlayerIdList(players) returns a comma seperated list of player ids (e.g. "0, 1, 2").

```
readableDatabase.query(
            "player_position",
            new String[]{"id", "player_id", "turn_number", "position"},
            "player_id IN (?)",
            new String[]{generatePlayerIdList(players)},
            null,
            null,
            null);
```

I have managed to get the query to work with the following code, but this is ugly when I am pulling in table and column names from other files (not shown here for readabilities sake) due to the amount of string concatenation.

```
readableDatabase.rawQuery(
            "SELECT id, player_id, turn_number, position " +
                    "FROM player_position " +
                    "WHERE player_id IN(" + generatePlayerIdList(players) + ")",
            null);
```

Comment: What concatenation you refer to? I mean from my perspective the second suggestion of your should be better performance-wise compared to the first one.

Comment: Following the advice here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#DefineContract the latter query becomes something like:

"SELECT " + PlayerPosition.ID + ", " + PlayerPosition.PLAYER_ID + ", " + PlayerPosition.TURN_NUMBER + ...

Using these constants is much nicer using the query method.

Comment: SQLite binding can only be done with literals, and not for providing a list of parameters. Unless you want to have comma separated question mark params, which will involve much more concatenation with no benefit, you should stay with your current solution. You can use String formatting if you want to keep it cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Android database API, parameters (`?`) are useful only for passing string values into the database.

The easiest way to handle multiple numbers it to insert them directly into the string:

```
db.query("player_position",
         new String[]{"id", "player_id", "turn_number", "position"},
         "player_id IN (" + generatePlayerIdList(players) + ")",
         null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Thanks, that is much cleaner than my orignal solution.